# text-decoration: underline with transformed element inside

Tags: css, underline, text-decorations

I have links which sometimes contain the character "•". With the webfont in use, the dot appears very small, so I apply `transform: scale(1.25);` This is only possible when wrapping the dot in a new box with `display: inline-block;`. But then, **the underline below the dot is gone**.

Here is the basic code

```css
.dot{
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1.25);
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

a:link{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  Text 
  <span class="dot">•</span> 
  Text
</a>
```

I can't use a border, because links sometimes span over two lines.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: You can possible to increase the font-size for webfont.

Comment: @stalinrajindian increasing the font-size will also increase the underline

Comment: increase the font for only dot class.

Comment: Or how about using a bigger dot. ● instead of •.

Comment: @MrLister I didn't know that there is a different dot - but this one is actually much too big (with the webfont in use) :-(

Comment: @stalinrajindian but then the underline thickness changes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with a gradient like below:

```css
.dot{
  display: inline-block;
  transform:scale(1.25);
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

a{
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
    transparent 0,transparent calc(1em - 1px),
    currentColor calc(1em - 1px),currentColor 1em) ;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  Text 
  <span class="dot">•</span> 
  Text
</a>
<div style="width:50px">
<a href="#" >
  Text 
  <span class="dot">•</span> 
  Text
</a>
</div>

<div style="width:50px">
<a href="#" style="font-size:20px">
  Text 
  <span class="dot">•</span> 
  Text
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea, haven't thought about that. The thing is, that in the following lines, the line may be longer than the text

Comment: @obs it's because I made it inline block .. check the update without inline-block

Comment: It's weird though that it doesn't work in Edge if you don't use currentcolor but "red" for example. And in Edge there is also a thin line on top.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below css.

```
.dot{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:44px;
  line-height:22px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: what where is the underline?

Comment: @MrLister inline-block element doesn't inherit the text-decoration ... try his code and you will not see any underline below the dot. The main issue is to keep the underline under the dot

Comment: @MrLister and if we remove inline-block, the font-size will make the underline of the dot bigger than the text which is not good

Comment: @MrLister considering the specification, the underline is not propagated `Note that text decorations are not propagated to any out-of-flow descendants, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as inline blocks and inline tables. They are also not propagated to inline children of inline boxes, although the decoration is applied to such boxes.` https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration